# What should I do to plot a picture

Tags: r

I want to plot a picture whose the beginning of xaxis and yaxis is 0.However, under my code, the result cann't match my requst. So I want to know where the mistakes are.Thanks!!

```
rm(list=ls())
axis.test<-function(){
  t<-seq(0,200)
  ntbase<-12/(1+exp(-(t-10)/25))
  nt1<-12/(1+exp(-(t-30)/25))
  nt2<-15.5334/(1+exp(-(t-20)/25))
  nt3<-10.6997/(1+exp(-(t-5)/25))
  nt4<-13.5906/(1+exp(-(t-30)/50))
  nt<-data.frame(cbind(ntbase,nt1,nt2,nt3,nt4))  matplot(t,nt,col=1:5,type='l',lwd=2,lty=1:5,ylab="population(100,000)",xaxs='i',yaxs='i',xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
  axis(side=1,at=c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200),labels=c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200),tck=0.03)
  axis(side=2,at=c(0,5,10,15,20),labels=c(0,5,10,15,20),tck=0.03)
}
axis.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

By "plotting a picture" I assume you mean plotting a graph. On a side note: I recommend using indentation and whitespaces to increase the readability of your code. Take a look at [Hadley's Advanced R Style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) to improve your R coding style.

You can specify axis limits through `matplot` arguments `xlim` and `ylim`

```
matplot(
    t, nt,
    col=1:5,
    type='l',
    lwd=2,
    lty=1:5,
    ylab="population(100,000)",
    xaxs='i', yaxs='i',
    xaxt='n', yaxt='n',
    xlim = c(0, 200),
    ylim = c(0, 20))
axis(
    side=1,
    at=seq(0,200,20),
    labels=seq(0,200,20),
    tck=0.03)
axis(
    side=2,
    at=seq(0,20, 5),
    labels=seq(0,20,5),
    tck=0.03)
```

[image]